# Can a unit set $C(K)$ form a commutative subdring?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I was asked to prove that the set $C(K)=\{a\in K| a\cdot r=r \cdot a, \forall\; r \in K\}$ forms a commutative subring inside the ring $K$.

However unit sets do not contain the element $0$, so they are not closed under addition. Therefore, $C(K)$ cannot be a subring.

I want to know if there is any possibility for $C(K)$ to form  a ring.

Comment: What is a "unit set" supposed to be? It seems to me that $0$ fits perfectly the defining property of $C(K)$.

Comment: The definitions is here [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)). Maybe I confused $C(K)$ with an unit set. What does the $C(K)$ mean then?, I'll remove my question after it.

Comment: Don't remove your question just because you feel it was not necessary after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the set of invertible elements of $K$, which are the elements $a\in K$ which satisfy
$$ \exists b\in K, ab=ba=1 $$
and its center (which you write $C(K)$ but is more commonly written $Z(K)$), which consists of the elements $a\in K$ such that
$$\forall b\in K, ab=ba.$$

They are completely different sets that have nothing to do with each other. The center is indeed a subring, and you can see that $0$ fits the definition ($0$ commutes with every element). The set of invertible elements (also called "units" to my great despair) is not a subring, but it is a subgroup for the multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification between the two definitions!